# How can i develop this idea in MDX SSAS?

Tags: ssas, mdx

Outstanding indicator

Outstanding amounts must not be aggregated in YTD.

Oustanding YTD at end of month X = Oustanding of month X

How can i develop this idea in MDX SSAS

Thank you guys to help i'm new with  BI

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to look at semi-additive measures, and in particular using the LastNonEmpty aggregation type.

This is only available in the Enterprise edition of SQL Server, although there are workarounds available in Standard Edition (see [here](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2008/04/semi-additive-measures-using-sql-server-standard/)).